# Update property on object in pinia array

Tags: vue.js, pinia

I'm just starting to use pinia and I have an array of objects in my state.

```
const useMyStore = defineStore('myState', () => {
    const myData = ref([]);
});
```

I want a method that will update the `name` property on one of the objects in the store. Should I write my pinia action like this?

```
function updateName(myObject, newName) {
    myData.value.find(o => o.id === myObject.id).name = newName;
}
```

or is it okay to directly mutate the object passed in?

```
function updateName(myObject, newName) {
    myObject.name = newName;
}
```

Other frameworks similar to pinia such as vuex and redux forbid directly mutating state so I'm not sure if this is okay in pinia.

The second one is what I would prefer but it seems it's maybe not the correct approach.

Comment: Whether something is okay to do is subjective and therefore not ideal for Stack Overflow (we want to give objective answers only).  I'll go ahead and give my opinion anyways: the pitfall with function #2 is if you don't pass in an object that references one of the objects in your store's `myData` then you're not saving the change to your store.  The first function also has a pitfall if `find` fails, in which case you're trying to set `name` of `undefined` (error).  It's up to you which one you'd rather deal with.

Comment: @yoduh looking back I didn't make it clear enough, but the intention of my question is whether or not pinia will function properly if the objects were directly mutated rather than using some other method. There are several frameworks similar to pinia in which directly mutating data can cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally googled the right term and found my answer [here](https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/discussions/1264) in the pinia repo. Basically pinia let's you directly mutate the state, even from within your component. You are not required to create a pinia action (or what is known as a mutation in vuex) to handle state changes. So the second method I posted is definitely better than the first but you could also just do

```
myObject.name = newName;
```

from inside your component and not even have the pinia action.

Comment: you can even mutate without pinia. i don't use pinia, seems just an overhead from old times when no ES modules exist. now you can export your reactive data from a module and mutate it directly without pinia

Comment: This may result in spaghetti code. It's still a good practice to mutate the state in an action in a declarative way. Mutations can be easily tracked through pinia devtools.

Comment: @EstusFlask in reality there's no direct mutations in business data, you call an api, it updates the state data (even through web sockets). so there's always some clear one-way binding

Comment: @EstusFlask a pinia store is a singleton,  you can do that with an ES module

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev You can do with a singleton exactly what you can do. I don't think it's reasonable to suggest to discard Pinia just because you can. Pinia is a wrapper around composition with additional features - batching, plugins, SSR, debugging. If you need some of them you may end up reinventing the wheel. To make it clear, I was commenting the answer, not the comment